# foreach in kotlin

Tags: foreach, kotlin

I see an example in the official site:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
  args filter {it.length() > 0} foreach {print("Hello, $it!")}
}
```

But when I copied it to idea, it reports that `foreach` is a unresolved reference.

What's the right code?

Comment: What page did you see it on? Thanks

Comment: @AndreyBreslav It's at the [bottom of this page](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/Kotlin/Hello,+world!#), and on [this page](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/Kotlin/Returns+and+jumps) and here in [the closures section](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/Kotlin/Function+literals).  I signed up for Confluence, but looks like you need special rights to alter the confluence wiki.  Looks like someone spotted it on [twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/leonardinius/status/189446323035062273) as well ;-)

Comment: There is still one, search `Filter created a collection for us, and we called foreach() on that collection`

Answer (score 61):

For other Kotlin newbees like me who are coming here just wanting to know how to loop through a collection, I found this in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/loops.html):

```
val names = listOf("Anne", "Peter", "Jeff")
for (name in names) {
    println(name)
}
```

Comment: Is this thread-safe? I haven't found information on this.

Answer (score 23):

It needs a capital `E` in `forEach` ie:

```
fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    args.asList().filter { it -> it.length > 0 }.forEach { println("Hello, $it!") }
}
```

Comment: doesn't compile .. aren't the dots needed? or am i hallucinating early in the a.m.

Comment: also it compllains about the parentheses after length

Comment: updated... things must have moved on...

Answer (score 6):

use this code:

```
  val nameArrayList = arrayListOf<String>("John", "mark", "mila", "brandy", "Quater") // ArrayList<String>
    nameArrayList.forEach {
        println("Name:$it")
    }

    val nameMutableList= mutableListOf<String>("John", "mark", "mila", "brandy", "Quater") // MutableList<String>
    nameMutableList.forEach {
        println("Name:$it")
    }

    val nameList= listOf<String>("John", "mark", "mila", "brandy", "Quater") // List<String>
    nameList.forEach {
        println("Name:$it")
    }
```